# How to show that if möbius transformation has an inverse, then it is injective?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f(z)$ be möbius transformation. 
How to show that if möbius transformation has an inverse, then it is injective? 
I mean why don't you use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Definition) definition to show injectivity of möbius transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function has an inverse, then it is injective. That has nothing to do with Möbius transformations and holds generally. For if $f(x) = f(y)$, then, by the definition of the inverse, we have

$$x = f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(f(y)) = y.$$

The reason why one computes the inverse of a Möbius transformation instead of showing

$$a\neq b \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$$

or its contrapositive is probably because it is not harder to compute the inverse, and it's quite useful to know the inverse.

Comment: So having inverse for $f$ is a application of definition of injectivity of $f$? I mean when a student sees this result when studying math in university? I mean is this connection between having inverse and being injective some kind of theorem or result from calculus courses or what?

Comment: Having an inverse is stronger than injectivity (if we view a function with a codomain; if we don't have an explicit codomain, invertibility is exactly injectivity). A map $f\colon A \to B$ has an inverse if and only if it is bijective, that is, injective and surjective. That is a result of basic set theory, and when I studied, there was a short section on basic set theory at the beginning of the first semester, where such things, de Morgan's laws, and so on were treated. But such things differ from country to country if not from university to university.

Comment: I tried to prove this using your version, but now I got stuck, because why if $w_1=w_2$, then $x=f^{-1}(w_1)=f^{-1}(w_2)=y$? is it possible to make intermediate steps with arguments for the steps. I mean especially arguments for $x=f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=y$

Comment: You must use that $w_1 = f(x)$ and $w_2 = f(y)$. Recall that by definition of the inverse of $f\colon A \to B$ we have $f^{-1}\circ f = \operatorname{id}_A$ and $f\circ f^{-1} = \operatorname{id}_B$. So we have $x = (f^{-1}\circ f)(x) = f^{-1}(f(x))$. By assumption, $f(x) = f(y)$. So replacing equals with equals, $x = f^{-1}(f(y)) = (f^{-1}\circ f)(y) = \operatorname{id}_A(y) = y$.

Comment: Is it possible to proof injectivity of $f$ by using this( $a\neq b \Rightarrow f(a) \neq f(b) $)? I could not find a way to proof injectivity in above way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Of course it is possible to prove injectivity of $f$ by proving $a\neq b \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$. The above _is_ the proof of injectivity for any map $f$ that has a left inverse (one does not even need a two-sided inverse). One proves the contrapositive, $f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$ by using the definition of a left inverse, and the assumption $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Well I just ask hint of how to prove injectivity of $f$ by using $a\neq b \Rightarrow f(a)\neq f(b)$ with assumptions given at the beginning of my question?

Comment: And I unfortunately don't understand what exactly you are asking. For any map $g\colon A \to B$, if it has a left inverse $h$, that is, $h\circ g = \operatorname{id}_A$, it follows that $g$ is injective, by the proof above. Are you asking for a way to show that a Möbius transformation is injective without using the contrapositive of the implication $a\neq b\implies f(a)\neq f(b)$? Then one would consider for example $$\frac{\alpha x+\beta}{\gamma x+\delta} - \frac{\alpha y+\beta}{\gamma y+\delta} = \frac{(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma)(x-y)}{(\gamma x+\delta)(\gamma y+\delta)}$$ for generic $x,y$,

Comment: and look at the cases where $f(x) = \infty$, $f(y)=\infty$ or one of $x,y$ is $\infty$ separately.

Comment: Ok. I would like to know how to show injectivity of a function $f(x)$ which has an inverse $f^{-1}$ by proving instead using contrapositive of $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$. I mean how to prove that $f$ is injective if $\exists f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}\circ f = Id_A$ and $f \circ f^{-1} = Id_B$ and you use definition of injectivity where $x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$. I tried to prove injectivity of $f$ by using $x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$, but did not managed to do that.

Comment: Let $a\neq b$ then $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a \neq b = f^{-1}(f(b))$, and therefore $f(a)\neq f(b)$. It's the same proof, just written down in a different manner. Or an indirect proof. Suppose there are $a\neq b$ with $f(a) = f(b)$, then $f$ has no inverse, since $f^{-1}(\{f(a)\}) \supset \{a,b\}$ contains at least two points.

Comment: But if you have $f(x)=x^2$(counter example) then $-1=a\neq b=1$, but still although $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}=\sqrt{x}$, still $f(-1)=f(1)$. Am I missing something, if you know what I mean?

Comment: The function $f\colon x \mapsto x^2$ does not have an inverse. Its restriction to certain subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ has an inverse, and the condition for the existence of an inverse is precisely that the domain does not contain two points $a\neq b$ with $f(a) = f(b)$.